# Does the writer write incorrectly in this paragraph?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I have a paragraph as follows:

> When you are comfortable, your body will be doing certain things automatically, just like it will tend to do certain things automatically when you are not comfortable. By knowing how you would be using your body if you were comfortable  under different circumstances and then consciously using your body that way, you can **make yourself comfortable more quickly.**

Does the expression “you can make yourself comfortable more quickly” mean “You can quickly make yourself more comfortable” right? I’m studying English and I was taught that the true English grammar is “make + sb + adj”, not “make + sb + adv”, so the writer write incorrectly “make yourself comfortable more quickly”, right?

Comment: But *comfortable* is an adjective!

Comment: The *more* applies to the adverb *quickly*, not the adjective *comfortable*. There is a difference in meaning if you reverse that.

Comment: How do you _"make yourself comfortable"_? You do it _"more quickly"._

Comment: @ P. E. Dant. I still don't understand. My English is not good. Can you explain in more detail for me?

Comment: @ Damkerng, So the clause will be " S + can + V + O + adj + more + adv". I rarely meet the grammar "adj + more + adv", so can you explain it for me? or better, can you rewrite it to be easier to understand?

Comment: @ Robusto can you rewrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is correct. Here, *more quickly* modifies *make*, so the meaning is "achieve the state of being comfortable faster than you would otherwise". The degree of comfort is not changed; rather, you attain it more quickly.

Note that this sentence does in fact follow your expected construction of *make + object + adjective*: *make yourself comfortable*. It just has an additional adverb phrase added to the end. However, this construction is not a requirement for using the transitive verb *make*. Consider:

- I will make it quickly
- I'll make you tomorrow

In both of these sentences, *make* has a slightly different meaning than in your example: *create something* in the first and *force to perform an action* in the second (with the action being understood and omitted). However, my point is that it is possible to have a valid *make + object + adverb* construction. English is a confusing language and rarely has absolute grammatical rules.

Answer (score 1):

> you can make yourself comfortable more quickly
>   you can more quickly make yourself comfortable

No, the author did not make a mistake here.  The "more quickly" is an adverb phrase.  It works at the end of the clause at least as well as it works in front of the verb "make".  In either position, "more quickly" modifies the verb.

Both versions have the same basic pattern: a form of the verb "make", a direct object, and a predicate adjective.  The adverb phrase isn't part of this pattern, but it doesn't interfere with it, either.

The verb "make" has more than one pattern:
verb + direct object
verb + indirect object + direct object
verb + direct object + predicate adjective
verb + direct object + predicate nominative

Adverb phrases can be added to any of these patterns.